# what does VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator) mean in chain link documentation

Tags: oracle, random, blockchain, ethereum, chainlink

I know that VRFCoordinatorV2Interface is an interface and we put the respective chain coordinator address in it. what does it signifies and how to visualise it.
OR
What will be the outcome when we put an address in a interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chainlink VRF Coordinator is a contract that is deployed to a blockchain that will check the randomness of each random number returned from a random node.

By putting "its address in an interface" you can programmatically interact with it from your smart contract. In other words, the function of your smart contract can call some other function from the VRF Coordinator function, like for example `createSubscription()`.

Comment: Thanks mann for putting it in simple terms!!